# Assigning the random password value to a particular column (cells)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a random password (*this code's running perfectly*), which will be pasted to the value to the Password text box, but facing a problem while calling the javascript function.

Here is my JavaScript :

```
function password() {
    var chars =   "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    i,j, cells, password;
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    for (i=0,j = rows.length; i<j;++i)
    {
    cells = rows[i].getElementsById('td');
    if(!cells.length)
    {continue;
    }
    password = cells[j].innerText;
    alert("hi "+password);
    }
    alert("Password is : "+randomstring);
    document.f2.password.value = randomstring;
}
```

Here is my Table :

```
<table name="table" id="table" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="2" border="1" bgcolor="" >
<tr name="tr" id="tr">
<th><input type="checkbox" name="allCheck" onclick="selectallMe()"></th>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Device</th>
<th>Feature Status</th>
<th>Policy</th>
<th>Password Management</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<%  while(rs.next()){ %>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkName" onclick="selectall()"></td> 
<td><input type="text"  name="empId" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%> "   disabled="disabled"  maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="device" value="<%= rs.getString(2)%>"   disabled="disabled" maxlength="10"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="features" value="<%= rs.getString(3)%>"  disabled="disabled" maxlength="60"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="policyName" value="<%= rs.getString(4)%>"  disabled="disabled" maxlength="10"></td>
<td id="td" name="td"><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value=""  ><input type="button" name="Password" value="Password" onclick="password()"><input type="reset"  name="Reset" value="Rseset"></td>
</tr>
<% } 
%>
</table>
```

In my JS what is going wrong?? As I want to iterate through Password column, `Password()` will assign the value to the Password cells.

Comment: what is the problem / error message?

Comment: Is it that your password button tries to call a function called `password()` but your function is defined with the name `randomString()`? Where are the `randform` and `randomfield` referenced on the last line of the function?

Comment: I am not getting any kind of message,but the code is not running.

Comment: `password = cells[j].innerText;` seems odd to me. j is a fixed value in this iterating loop (and one more than your number of columns since the array is probably zero-based). You probably meant to use `password = cells[i].innerText;`

Comment: @nnnnnn > I have changed the name,but what I feel that password() is not running.

Comment: Use the Firefox plugin "Firebug". It will tell you what is wrong ;)

Comment: `.getElementsById('td')` should be `.getElementsByTagName('td')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would prefer to put this in a comment but i don't have the reputation to yet.

first off is there a specific reason you want the cells to be text input types? Since you are just disabling them on creation. 
also look into the rows[index].cells(); and table.rows(); methods in JS. these will give you an array of the cells and rows. from there you can iterate to where you want. 
visit to learn more http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/tableproperties.shtml

hope it helps